# Why does my class field appear as undefined when referencing a value set in the constructor

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am trying to set a field value using a basic calculation that uses values set in my constructor, though for some reason when i reference some of the values initialised in my constructor, i get TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined.

Though when i reference `this` without trying to access any of the values set in my constructor (margin or dimension) , i do not get this error and can see the initialised object.

```
class viz {
  constructor(dimension, margin) {
    this.dimension = dimension;
    this.margin = margin;
  }

  width = this.dimension.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  height = this.dimension.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
}

const margin = { left: 40, right: 40, top: 40, bottom: 20 };
const dimension = { width: 1000, height: 600 };
let visual = new viz(dimension,margin)
```

Comment: I don't think you have access to `this` in property initialisers.

Comment: Object constants make less sense.

Comment: @JavaScript There is no such thing as an object constant, unless you're talking about `Object.freeze`. The fact you're passing values stored in a `const` to the constructor does not make the arguments the constructor takes constants.

Comment: @VLAZ i do have access to this in property initialisers because when i replace the property values with just a ```this``` rather than ```this.dimension``` or ```this.margin```, an object is returned with all the information created in the constructor.

Comment: @JavaScript why is it object constants make no sense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class fields, de-sugared, always run near the *beginning* of the constructor, before properties are assigned to `this` (though class fields are assigned after a `super` call, if present - and a `super` call must be done before references to `this` in the constructor too):

```js
class Parent {
}
class viz extends Parent {
  constructor(dimension, margin) {
    console.log('before super in constructor');
    super();
    console.log('after super');
    this.dimension = dimension;
    this.margin = margin;
  }

  something = console.log('class field');
  width = this.dimension.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  height = this.dimension.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
}

const margin = { left: 40, right: 40, top: 40, bottom: 20 };
const dimension = { width: 1000, height: 600 };
let visual = new viz(dimension,margin)
```

You can't use a class field if you want to reference properties created in the constructor. You'll have to put that functionality into the constructor instead.

```js
class viz {
  constructor(dimension, margin) {
    this.dimension = dimension;
    this.margin = margin;
    
    
    this.width = this.dimension.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = this.dimension.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
  }
}

const margin = { left: 40, right: 40, top: 40, bottom: 20 };
const dimension = { width: 1000, height: 600 };
let visual = new viz(dimension,margin)

console.log(visual);
```

Comment: "Class fields, de-sugared, always run near the beginning of the constructor, before properties are assigned to this",  if this is the case then why is it when we replace the ```something = console.log('class field')``` with ```something = console.log(this)``` we get an object that shows all the assigned constructor properties ? Surely this suggests they're assigned after the constructor ?

Comment: @KvothesLute Don't let yourself be fooled by `console.log`.

Comment: @KvothesLute [the console is lazy when evaluating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays). So, you *don't* see the state of `this` at the time of the log. The `console.log` prints the reference and at the time you examine it, it's already been populated.